# issue in installing postgresql 9.3.4 on Windows server 2003 x64

Tags: postgresql

Hello i really did all what i know to install the PostgreSQL 9.3.4 on my windows 2003 server x64, but i'm always stopped with this error :

please see the error : http://oi57.tinypic.com/s4tb8i.jpg

I really don't know what to do , if i click OK then when i go to the windows services list i don't find the PostgreSQL service so i can't Start the service .

can any one please help me to install it correctly .

PS: i've followed all steps in the : [wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Troubleshooting_Installation)

many thanks .

here's the installer log * where i get " Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb " :

```
Called IsVistaOrNewer()...
    'winmgmts' object initialized...
    Version:5.2
    MajorVersion:5
Ensuring we can write to the data directory (using cacls):
    Executing batch file 'rad22ADE.bat'...
    processed dir: C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data

    Executing batch file 'rad22ADE.bat'...
    The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "Administrator".
This user must also own the server process.

The database cluster will be initialized with locale "English_United States.1252".
The default text search configuration will be set to "english".

fixing permissions on existing directory C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data ... initdb: could not change permissions of directory "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.2/data": Permission denied

Called Die(Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb)...
Failed to initialise the database cluster with initdb

Script stderr:
 Program ended with an error exit code

Error running cscript //NoLogo "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2/installer/server/initcluster.vbs" "NT AUTHORITY\NetworkService" "postgres" "****" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2" "C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\data" 5432 "DEFAULT" 0 : Program ended with an error exit code
Problem running post-install step. Installation may not complete correctly
 The database cluster initialisation failed.
Creating Uninstaller
Creating uninstaller 25%
Creating uninstaller 50%
Creating uninstaller 75%
Creating uninstaller 100%
Installation completed
Log finished 05/02/2014 at 04:04:04
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the exact same issue on a 32bit 2003 server.

For some reason it seems to fail on the very same part, the setting of permissions on the data dir.

I thought it was failing because I only had Service Pack 1, which doesn't come with icalcs.exe  (it's introduced in SP2), but it kept failing even after upgrade to SP2.

Temporarily fixed it by setting full control privileges to everyone to the data prior to re-running the installer. I'm still investigating the reason and looking for a permanent fix.

Comment: Here is a good explanation of the problem. It would seem that the installer is effectively broken for this setup. http://forums.enterprisedb.com/posts/list/3984.page

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you try installing it manually using the binaries they supply: [Here](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload)

Comment: many thanks , so there's no other way than install it manually using the binaries ?

Comment: Given the error it seems to be failing to 'initcluster' so something else might have gone wrong earlier in the installer as well. The best option is to do a manual install and then you can figure out exactly what is failing if it doesn't then work.